# How to find total storage capacity of iphone and actuall app sandbox size more accurately though ios programe

Tags: ios

I am trying to find actual space and free space and our app using space of iPhone.
Can any one help me out. i used following code for total space and free space but it is not accurate..

```
uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

if (dictionary) {
    NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
    NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
    totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %ld", [error domain], [error code]);
}
```

Comment: What do you find inaccurate about the results of this call?

Comment: The size actual space of the device and what i got are not matching